How to Animate the Top Half of a Flip Card Falling with Framer Motion in React?
I'm trying to create a countdown timer in React using Framer Motion, where the digits change with a flip effect. I want the top half of the card to "fall" or "flip" down when the digit changes, creating a smooth animation effect. However, I'm having trouble getting the flip animation to work correctly. Here's the code I have so far:


import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'

const Countdown = () => {
  const initialCount = 2 * 24 * 60 * 60
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount)

  // useEffect para decrementar a contagem a cada segundo
  useEffect(() => {
    if (count > 0) {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => setCount(count - 1), 1000)
      return () => clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  }, [count])

  // Função para formatar o tempo em dias, horas, minutos e segundos
  const formatTime = (seconds: number) => {
    const days = Math.floor(seconds / (24 * 60 * 60))
    const hours = Math.floor((seconds % (24 * 60 * 60)) / 3600)
    const minutes = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60)
    const secs = seconds % 60
    return { days, hours, minutes, secs }
  }

  const { days, hours, minutes, secs } = formatTime(count)

  const FlipDigit = ({ digit }: { digit: string }) => {
    return (
      <div className='relative w-20 h-32 bg-gray-800 text-white rounded-lg shadow-lg overflow-hidden'>
        <div className='absolute inset-0 flex flex-col'>
          <div className='h-1/2 w-full overflow-hidden'>
            <AnimatePresence mode='popLayout'>
              <motion.div
                key={`top-${digit}`}
                initial={{ rotateX: 0 }}
                animate={{ rotateX: 0 }}
                exit={{ rotateX: 90 }}
                transition={{ duration: 0.3, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
                style={{
                  transformOrigin: 'bottom',
                  backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
                  boxShadow: '0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                }}
                className='absolute inset-0 flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-700'
              >
                <span className='text-6xl'>{digit}</span>
              </motion.div>
            </AnimatePresence>
          </div>
          <div className='h-1/2 w-full overflow-hidden'>
            <div className='absolute inset-0 flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-700'>
              <span className='text-6xl'>{digit}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='absolute top-1/2 w-full h-[1px] bg-gray-600'></div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  // Componente para a unidade de tempo (dias, horas, etc.)
  const FlipUnit = ({ value, label }: { value: number; label: string }) => {
    const paddedValue = String(value).padStart(2, '0')
    return (
      <div className='flex flex-col items-center'>
        <FlipDigit digit={paddedValue} />
        <div className='mt-2 text-xl text-gray-400'>{label}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className='flex justify-center items-center h-screen bg-gray-900'>
      <div className='flex space-x-8'>
        <FlipUnit value={days} label='DAYS' />
        <FlipUnit value={hours} label='HOURS' />
        <FlipUnit value={minutes} label='MINUTES' />
        <FlipUnit value={secs} label='SECONDS' />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Countdown



Here is the code in codesandbox
